# What's the difference between a Multiple pages PWA with a SPA pwa?

Tags: angular, web, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

recently I created a SPA with angular and I config it to be PWA ( a Single page Application that is PWA) and recently I found that we can also change a regular web page (MPA) to PWA as well

So my question is

what's the difference between a Multi pages web (config to be a pwa) with SPA (config to be a PWA)?

all of us know that most important benefit of SPA is a without refresh webpage so when I create a regular web app and config or convert it to a PWA and when it save on Mobile or local storage then the End user can't see or fill the refresh on the Page because its fast load so

why we have spend more time to develop a SPA and change it to PWA when we can easily create a regular webpage and change it PWA?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Both Multi-page (MPA) and Single-page (SPA) behave the same way in a PWA, specifically they all loaded from the service worker, and make AJAX calls through the service worker.

Additionally, in an MPA, if you've already cached the pages, users likely won't notice switching between pages.

The real work is making sure that your transactions (add/update/delete), work offline.  This is the same for SPA or MPA.

Comment: So in this case why people use SPA when they want to create a PWA instead of using MPA?

Comment: Good question, I think maybe it's because people started writing SPAs before PWA became widely understood.  I think many might incorrectly assume the technology only works with SPA, or maybe they don't take the time to understand how PWA applies to MPA too.  All (very) opinionated guesses, but developers can be are herd animals the follow the pack, with out research...

Comment: One benefit of a SPA is that you can transition from different pages.  In a MPA it is not possible to create any smooth transition because the page refreshes

Comment: Now there's the [View Transition API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/View_Transitions_API) (aka. Shared Element Transitions) which allows MPAs to have as smooth page transitions as SPAs.